# spawn ENOENT error in windows while running execFile (node js)

Tags: node.js, child-process, execfile

Im trying to run a C file using child process in node.js. Im using execFile to do this, the 'test' file is in the same folder. The same program runs on linux and gives the output but doesn't run on windows. It shows `error: spawn ./test ENONET` on windows. What do I do?

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process')
execFile('./test', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
if(error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`)
    return
}
if(stderr) {
    console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
}
console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`) })
```

Edit: I tried it with this file 'somefile.sh' which is in the same directory

```
#!/bin/bash
//ls -lh //for linux
-dir //for windows
```

It shows

```
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
←[90m    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:403:11)←[39m
←[90m    at spawn (child_process.js:553:9)←[39m
←[90m    at execFile (child_process.js:237:17)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Projects\childprocess\exec_file.js:6:1)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m {
  errno: ←[33m-4094←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'UNKNOWN'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn'←[39m
}
```

I also tried for exec using a single command and it gives the output for the below code.

```
    const {exec} = require('child_process')

exec('pwd', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`)
        return
    }
    if(stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`)
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`)
})
```

Output shows the present working direactory.
This is the tutorial I referred: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbmFvCbVDqo&t=441s

Comment: And your node & compiled c file are in the same directory? Does the file have a extension? e.g.`.exe`? Have you tried it with a file extension?

Comment: Yes, same directory. But the file originally doesn't have an extension. When I run it as './test.c' and './test.exe' it still shows the same error.

Comment: Can you add the c source or a simple c dummy that i can try it by myself? Have you tried it with other methods from the `child_process module, like `exec`?

Comment: Yes i've tried exec and gave pwd command, it works for exec but not execfile. I've added the sample code in edit.